# Why did media query stopped working on brackets?

Tags: html, css

So basically I was working on the adaptable part of my code and everything was working smootly with my media query and everything else, suddenly it stopped working(? I don't know what's wrong or why is it happening now, I'm guessing there's some mistake I can't see with my css but I can't find it.

```
*{
    
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-height: 2080px;
}

body{background-image: url(../img/aaa.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;   
    z-index: 2;
    max-height: 2080px;
    background-color:pink;
}

footer{ background: #111;
  left: 0; bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  
  z-index: 2;
  clear: both;
  position: absolute;
  width: 98%;
  height: 10%;
  margin-bottom: -100%;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

footer a{
    
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:monospace;
    padding-left: 8%;
    padding: 5px 14px;
   
}

.todo{ display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    
    
  
}

.fondo{
    
    background: #FFF;
  height: 2512px;
  width: 98%;
   
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
  margin-top: -23%;
    z-index: 1;
    
}

.nombre h1{
    margin-top: -38%;
    font-family: cursive;
    margin-left: 1%;
    color: white;
    font-size: 230%;
    text-shadow: 5px 4px  lightblue;
    z-index: 2;

}
   
.menu{
    
    background: #fff;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    box-shadow: 5px 0 10px rgba(0,0,0, .5);
    
}

.logo{
    
    color: pink;
    font-family: "Comic Sans Ms", cursive;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 240%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    text-shadow: 2px 3px  lightblue;
}
.items{
    
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    margin-right: 6%;
}

.items li{
    
    border-radius: 1%;
    margin: 0 16px;
    
}

.items li a{
    
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 110%;
    display: block;
    color: lightblue;
    font-family: cursive;
}

li a:hover{
    
    background-color:lightcyan;
    padding: 5px;
    transition: .4s;

}

.bts-menu{
    
    margin-right: 10%;
    font-size: 150%;
    color: pink;
    cursor:pointer;
    display: none;
}

ul.show{
    
    top: 65px;
}

.img-frontal {
    
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-left: 18%;
    z-index: 2;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 60%;
    
}

.img-frontal h1{
    position: absolute;
    font-family:"Comic Sans Ms", cursive;
    font-size: 590%;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 14%;
    margin-top: -27%;
    z-index: 2;
    
}

.img-frontal p{
    position: absolute;
        color: black;
        z-index: 2;
        margin-left: 20%;
        font-family: "Comic Sans ms", cursive;
        color: white;
        margin-top: -25%;
        font-size: 223%
    
}

.front{
    
    max-width: 80%;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-top: 10%;
    
}


.back-content h1{
    margin: auto;
    margin-left: 15%;
    font-family: cursive;
    margin-top: 34%;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 690%;
    color: pink;
    letter-spacing:20px;
    text-shadow: 5px 4px  lightblue;
    
}

.back-content img{
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    height: 30%;
    margin-top: 50%;
    margin-left: 3%;
    border-style:dashed;
    border-color: pink;

    
}

hr.someClass {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 70%;
  height: 5px;
position: absolute;
    margin-top: 43%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    z-index: 2;
}

.text1 h1{
    
   color:lightblue;
    
    z-index: 2;
    margin-top: -34%;
    margin-left: 58%;
    font-size: 450%;
    font-family: "Comic Sans Ms", cursive;
    text-shadow: 5px 4px  pink;
}

.text1 p{
    
    color:black;
    
    z-index: 2;
    margin-left: 55%;
    font-size: 150%;

}

.bubbly-button{
    
  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0.6em;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  appearance: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: none;
  background-color: deeppink;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 25px rgba(255, 0, 130, 0.5)
  
}

.cajas{
    
   
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 43px;
  margin-top: 13%;
}

.cajas h1{
    
    font-size: 120%;
    margin: 0 0 26px 0;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    
}
.contenido1{
    
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 16px;
  padding: 33px;
  border: 3% solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.otros{
    
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    
    
}

.card-1, .card-2{
    
   margin-right: 1%;
    
}

.card-1, .card-2, .card-3 {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24); 
  
   
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
}

.card-1:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
}

.card-2:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
}

.card-3:hover {box-shadow: 0 14px 28px
  rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
}


.button2{
    
  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0.6em;
  margin-left: -2%;
  padding: 2em 3em;
  border-style: dashed;
  appearance: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: none;
  background-color: deeppink;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 25px rgba(255, 0, 130, 0.5)}
```

As I said it was working fine with the media and then it didn't, the code is kind of long so yeah

```
      @media screen and (max-width:952px){ 
          .logo{
              
              font-size: 170%;
              padding-left: 5%; 
          }
 
          .items{
              
              font-size: 80%;
          }

        .img-frontal p{
            
            font-size: 110%;
            top: 60%;
          }
          
          .img-frontal h1{
            
            font-size: 310%;
            top: 63%;
          }
          
          .back-content h1{
              
              font-size: 500%;
              margin-top: 30%;
          }
          
          .text1 h1{
              
              font-size: 320%;
              margin-top: -36%
          }
          
          
          
          .text1 p{
              
              font-size: 80%;
          }
          
          .fondo{
              
              height:1485px; 
          }
          
          .cartas{
              
              width: 30%;
              height: 10%;
              margin-left:1%;
              margin-right: 2%;
              position: relative;
              flex-direction: row;
          }
          
          footer{
              
              margin-bottom: -105%;
          }
          
}

     @media screen and (max-width:858px){ 
          .menu{
              
              height:65px;
          } 
         
         .bts-menu
         {
             
            display: inline-flex;
         }
         
         .items
            {
                
                position: fixed;
                width: 100vw;
                height: calc(100%-65px);
                background: darkgray;
                top: -100vh;
                text-align: center;
                transition: all .4s;
                flex-direction: column;
         }

         .item li

         {
             
             margin: 30px 0 0;
             line-height: 30px;
         }
         
         .items li a

         {
             
             font-size: 190%;
             color: #fff;
             font-weight: bold;
         }
         
         .img-frontal p{
            
            font-size: 100%;
            top: 60%;
          }
          
          .img-frontal h1{
            
            font-size: 290%;
            top: 60%;
          }
         
         .back-content h1{
              
              font-size: 430%;
              margin-top: 30%;
             
          }
         
         .text1 h1{
              
              font-size: 280%;
              margin-top: -36%
          }
          
          
          
          .text1 p{
              
              font-size: 77%;
          }
         
         .cartas{
              
              width: 30%;
              height: 10%;
              margin-left:1%;
              margin-right: 2%;
              position: relative;
              flex-direction: row;
          }
.fondo{
              
              height:1385px; 
          }
.contenido1 h3{
              
              font-size: 85%;
          }
         
         .button2{
              
              margin-left: -6%;
          }
         
}



 @media screen and (max-width:858px) and (orientation:landscape){ 
          .items li{
            margin: 5px 0 0;
              
          }
     
     .items {
              
overflow: scroll;
height: calc(100%-65px);
          }

      }


@media screen and (max-width:858px){ 
        
         
         .img-frontal p{
            
            font-size: 80%;
            top: 44%;
            
          }
          
          .img-frontal h1{
            
            font-size: 230%;
            top: 47%;
             
          }
         
         .back-content h1{
              
              font-size: 370%;
              margin-top: 30%;
             
          }
         
         .text1 h1{
              
              font-size: 230%;
              margin-top: -36%;
             margin-top: -35%;
          }
          
          
          
          .text1 p{
              
              font-size: 68%;
              margin-top: -3%;
          }
         
         .contenido1{
              
              padding: 15%;
          }
.fondo{
              
              height:1185px; 
          }
.contenido1 h3{
              
              font-size: 70%;
          }
         
         .button2{
              
              margin-left: -6%;
          }
         footer{
              
              margin-bottom: -99%;
          }
}


@media screen and (max-width:964px){ 
        
         
         .img-frontal p{
            
            font-size: 85%;
            top: 92%;
          }
          
          .img-frontal h1{
            
            font-size: 248%;
            top: 91.5%;
          }
         
         .back-content h1{
              
              font-size: 420%;
              margin-top: 32%;
             
          }
         
         .text1 h1{
              
              font-size: 260%;
              margin-top: -33%;
             
          }
          
          
          
          .text1 p{
              
              font-size: 80%;
              margin-top: -1%;
          }
         
         .contenido1{
              
              padding: 15%;
          }
.fondo{
              
              height:1294px; 
          }
.contenido1 h3{
              
              font-size: 70%;
          }
         
         .button2{
              
              margin-left: -6%;
          }
         footer{
              
              margin-bottom: -110%;
          }
}

@media screen and (max-width:964px){ 
        
         
         .img-frontal p{
            
            font-size: 50%;
            top: 92%;
          }
          
          .img-frontal h1{
            
            font-size: 248%;
            top: 91%;
          }
         
         .back-content h1{
              
              font-size: 400%;
              margin-top: 32%;
             
          }
         
         .text1 h1{
              
              font-size: 230%;
              margin-top: -33%;
             
          }
          
          
          
          .text1 p{
              
              font-size: 40%;
              margin-top: -1%;
          }
         
         .contenido1{
              
              padding: 15%;
          }
.fondo{
              
              height:1294px; 
          }
.contenido1 h3{
              
              font-size: 70%;
          }
         
         .button2{
              
              margin-left: -6%;
          }
         footer{
              
              margin-bottom: -110%;
          }
}
```

Comment: I want to help you but don't know how. Can you share a live link to the web page?

Answer (score 1):

One definite issue within your media query styles is this:

```css
.items {
  …
  height: calc(100%-65px);
}
```

When using `calc`, you need to put a space around the operator or that `CSS` is invalid:

```css
.items {
  …
  height: calc(100% - 65px);
}
```

Comment: I already fixed it but it's still not working(?